# What is origin of mankind according to common wh40k beliefs?

Tags: lore, religions-and-deities, warhammer-40k

In wh40k universe, the Imperium of Man is based on religion that generally says "emperor protects" etc. But is there some religious explanation regarding origin of mankind? I'm pretty sure that Emperor himself would propagate scientific explanation based on evolution etc. But as we know, Imperium is far from what Emperor would want. So how do people of Imperium explain themselves such fundamental existential questions?

Since fandom wiki doesn't provide such answers, I assume it varies on world-to-world basis and can be decided by the Game Master alone.

Or are there some interesting canonical views on that?

Comment: This might actually fit better on [scifi.se] since it's purely about the lore of a universe, and one that didn't start out as an RPG.

Comment: Relevant meta discussion: [Are questions about Warhammer 40k Lore on-topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11640)

Comment: This is on-topic here, but you might get a better answer at the previously-mentioned SciFi & Fantasy stack.

Answer (score 2):

In most ways, the history of humanity in Warhammer 40k **parallels our own**. However, Codex: Necrons (3rd Edition), hints at the potential of deeper truths. The exact quote there (page 9) states:

> Long ago, before the Fall, the Mon-keigh were nothing. They were comical tree-beasts, part of the eco-system of their world, but with no greater role defined for them by the Old Ones. [...] In this power vacuum the **lesser creations of the Old Ones, such as the Mon-keigh**, developed in unforseeable ways. Raw, elemental evolution took a hold, turning these noisy but harmless beasts into the life form that now infested a million worlds.

So at least according to the Eldar point-of-view, humans were created by the Old Ones, *an obviously heretical idea without merit*, then largely left to the tender mercies of evolution after the Old Ones met the C'tan in the same way this sentence met this period.

Comment: Necrons are not Eldar.

Comment: The viewpoint character in that section is an Eldar Farseer.

Comment: That may be what the Eldar think, but the question seems to be about beliefs found within the Imperium, not any of the alien cultures.

Comment: Hence the first sentence and the text in italics. Natural evolution, unlike all the unnatural xenos, who must be purged with fire, praise the Emperor.